# Need help with understanding CSS3 animations

Tags: css, css-animations

I am trying to learn animations in CSS3 but Im stuck with all the documentation out there.  I have this code:

```
h1{
        -webkit-animation: moveDown 1.s ease-in-out .6s backwards;
        -moz-animation: moveDown 1s ease-in-out 0.6s backwards;
        -o-animation: moveDown 1s ease-in-out 0.6s backwards;
        -ms-animation: moveDown 1s ease-in-out 0.6s backwards;
        animation: moveDown 1s ease-in-out 0.6s backwards;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes moveDown{
        0% { 
            -webkit-transform: translateY(-300px); 
            opacity: 0;
        }
        100% { 
            -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);  
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }

    @-moz-keyframes moveDown{
        0% { 
            -moz-transform: translateY(-40px); 
            opacity: 0;
        }
        100% { 
            -moz-transform: translateY(0px);  
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }

    @-o-keyframes moveDown{
        0% { 
            -o-transform: translateY(-40px); 
            opacity: 0;
        }
        100% { 
            -o-transform: translateY(0px);  
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }
```

- I understand that `webkit-animation` - `animation` is the call for each browser.
- I dont understand the modeDown.  Is that like a variable?
- 1s is the length of the animations?
- ease-in-out I dont understand
- .6s is the delay
- I dont get the backwards nor am able to find any info on it

Is this for the timing sequence?

```
@-moz-keyframes moveDown{
    0% { 
        -moz-transform: translateY(-40px); 
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% { 
        -moz-transform: translateY(0px);  
        opacity: 1;
    }
```

Ive read [this](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transitions/), [this](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/masterclass-css-animations) and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_animations).  Does someone mind explaining this better to me?
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I dont understand the modeDown. Is that like a variable?**

The animation `moveDown` starts at `opacity:0` and `-moz-transform:translateY(-40px)` and finishes at `opacity: 1` and `-moz-transform: translateY(0px)`. This means that it starts completely transparent and shifted 40 pixels above where it normally is and ends at its regular positioning and fully opaque.

```
@-moz-keyframes moveDown{
    0% { 
        -moz-transform: translateY(-40px); 
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% { 
        -moz-transform: translateY(0px);  
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

**1s is the length of the animations?**

Yes.

**ease-in-out I dont understand**

`ease-in-out` is an [animation-timing-function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/animation-timing-function), this specifies how to transition from 0% to 100% (or the other way). Ease in out will each in and each out of the animation so the change won't be so abrupt, another example is linear which will change in a completely uniform fashion.

There is a [handy chart on this page](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/timing-function/#.UV6hY5NQHNs) that explains the difference better than words.

**.6s is the delay**

Yes.

**I dont get the backwards nor am able to find any info on it**

`backwards` and `forwards` are used for [animation-fill-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/animation-fill-mode) which says switch direction the animation should go. If `forwards` is chosen then the animation will run from 0% (transparent) to 100% (opaque), if `backwards` is chosen then the animation will run from 100% to 0%.

### Further reading

- [The Art of the Web - timing functions](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/timing-function/)
- [CSS3 animations spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/)
- [Mozilla developer - animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/animation)

Answer (score 1):

It's often better to read the actual [working drafts](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-css3-animations-20130219/) (or recommendations) from the W3C, since they provide complete information:

> I dont understand the modeDown. Is that like a variable?

You could say so, however *variables*  are usually mutable, while `moveDown` is simply an identifier for an animation. So it's simply the animation's name:

> Keyframes are specified using a specialized CSS at-rule. A @keyframes rule consists of the keyword "@keyframes", followed by an identifier giving a name for the animation (which will be referenced using ‘animation-name’), followed by a set of style rules (delimited by curly braces). [[source]](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-css3-animations-20130219/#keyframes)

---

> - 1s is the length of the animations?
> - ease-in-out I dont understand
> - .6s is the delay

The [`animation`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-css3-animations-20130219/#animation-shorthand-property) property is a shorthand for several `animation-*` properties at once:

```
<single-animation> = <single-animation-name> || <time> || <single-animation-timing-function> || <time> || <single-animation-iteration-count> || <single-animation-direction> || <single-animation-fill-mode> || <single-animation-play-state>
```

As you can see the first property is the animation's name (see above), the second the actual length, the third one is the timing-function, in your case `ease-in-out`. This is [basically a bezier-curve](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-transitions-20120403/#transition-timing-function-property) which modifies the timing. For example you want to speed up the animation at the beginning and the end, and have a more linear behaviour in the middle.

`.6s` is indeed the delay between the animations.

> - I dont get the backwards nor am able to find any info on it

Have a look at [`animation-fill-mode`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-css3-animations-20130219/#animation-fill-mode-property):

> If the value for ‘animation-fill-mode’ is ‘backwards’, then the animation will apply the property values defined in the keyframe that will start the first iteration of the animation, during the period defined by ‘animation-delay’. These are either the values of the ‘from’ keyframe (when ‘animation-direction’ is ‘normal’ or ‘alternate’) or those of the ‘to’ keyframe (when ‘animation-direction’ is ‘reverse’ or ‘alternate-reverse’).